# Can i hide a data field in a error log of a view?

Tags: php, laravel, logging

I've inherited a proyect and updated it from laravel 5.6 to laravel 8.

After the update, the daily error logs got way larger than before. Turns out, there is a model, general settings (*'gs'*), which gets inyected in all the views since some genius decided to place some html views inside it.

Taking out this general settings model is on my priorities, but it is literally in half the views and is a mayor refactor to remove it.

Right now i need to hide this model from the error log because i need to fix other stuff first, and it's really annoying to diagnose the server's error log.

Log after applying a bit of format to improve legibility for the example:

```
[2021-04-26 12:33:42] local.ERROR: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object 
(View: /home/vagrant/code/proyect/resources/views/vendor/shop_page.blade.php) 
{
 "view": {"view":"/home/vagrant/code/proyect/resources/views/vendor/shop_page.blade.php",
 "data": {"gs": "
    <pre class=sf-dump id=sf-dump-1243871242 data-indent-pad=\"  \">
    <span class=sf-dump-note>App\\GeneralSetting</span> {<a class=sf-dump-ref>#960</a><samp data-depth=1 class=sf-dump-expanded>
    #<span class=sf-dump-protected title=\"Protected property\">guarded</span>: []
    +<span class=sf-dump-public title=\"Public property\">timestamps</span>: <span class=sf-dump-const>false</span>
    #<span class=sf-dump-protected title=\"Protected property\">connection</span>: \"<span class=sf-dump-str title=\"5 characters\">mysql</span>\"
    #<span class=sf-dump-protected title=\"Protected property\">table</span>: \"<span class=sf-dump-str title=\"16 characters\">general_settings</span>\"

....

"}},
"exception":"[object] (Facade\\Ignition\\Exceptions\\ViewException(code: 0): Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: /home/vagrant/code/prendasya/resources/views/vendor/shop_page.blade.php) at /home/vagrant/code/prendasya/resources/views/vendor/shop_page.blade.php:256)
[stacktrace]
```

Note: Each entry is aprox 8300 lines long

Is there some way to hide 'gs' inside 'data' ?

Thanks!

Comment: I am thinking if you could hide it using the [`Error Handling`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors) but I never used it widely so I have nearly no experience to help you with it. Maybe you read that part of the documentation and you come up with a good solution to it as no one said anything here to help you.

Comment: @matiaslauriti After diggin' in the source code i found out that Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException has a method called dumpViewData and is responsible for the HTML dump.

If i just override the exceptions viewData property with a the information in json the log still reports some of the fields i want .